# O meu if não está funcionando como o esperado

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, if, echo

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM myTable")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {

if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
} else{
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
    echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
    echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
    echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
    echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
}

}
```

A coluna chamada "entry_type" tem apenas dois valores possíveis: "pagina" ou "post", esse código deveria dar `echo` na `meta` tag que está no `if` quando o `entry_type = pagina`, e dar `echo` nas `meta` tags que estão no `else` quando o `entry_type = post`.

Esse código está duplicando as `meta` tags de acordo com quantos registros tem os valores `pagina` ou `post` na coluna `entry_type` do meu DB. Independentemente se a página em que estou é igual a `entry_type = pagina` ou `entry_type = post`. E esse código tambem está imprimindo as `meta` tags do `if` e do `else` juntas.

**Edit:** Resolvi o problema da duplicação:

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM myTable WHERE entry_type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY entry_type")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {

    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
    } else{
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
        echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
    }

 }
```

Esse código está imprimindo as `meta` tags do `if` e do `else` juntas. Ignorando a instrução do `if`.

O que tem de errado no meu código, e como resolvo?

Esse é o resultado do `print_r`:

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM myTable WHERE entry_type IS NOT NULL GROUP BY entry_type")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {
print_r($mt); //Resultado 1

    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){
    print_r($mt); //Resultado 2

        //codigo postado na pergunta

    } else{    
      print_r($mt); //Resultado 3

        //codigo postado na pergunta

    }

}
```

- **Resultado 1** :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) ) Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] => Array ( [entry_type] =>
>   post [0] => post ) )

- **Resultado 2** :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) )

- **Resultado 3** :

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [entry_type] => pagina [0] => pagina ) [1] =>
>   Array ( [entry_type] => post [0] => post ) )

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83716/discussion-on-question-by-user236945896-o-meu-if-nao-esta-funcionando-como-o-esp)

Comment: Ótimo. Fiquei em dúvida se podia utilizar o recurso do chat para tal finalidade.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo seu `var_dump` aparentemente o primeiro índice do seu vetor `$mt` tem o valor `null` na coluna `entry_type`. Ou seja como `null` não é `página` ele vai cair em seu `else`.

Por segurança aconselho você colocar um `else if` no local. Segue exemplo de como o código ficaria:

```
$mt = $conn->query("SELECT entry_type FROM myTable")->fetchAll();

foreach ($mt as $FB) {
    $type = '';
    if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'pagina'){ 
        $type = 'website';
    } else if ($FB['entry_type'] == 'post') {
        $type = 'article';
    }

    if($type == 'website' || $type == 'article') {
      echo '<meta property="og:type" content="'.$type.'">';
      echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
      echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
      break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Desculpe não entendi, qual else?

Comment: aaah sim, agora eu entendi. então, tá certo de acordo com o var_dump ele entrou no local correto. como você tá testando essas tags?

Comment: Usando o chrome digita o endereço view-source:http://localhost/seuscript.php e veja se realmente não está imprimindo

Comment: ele está imprimindo mais de uma vez a meta tag

Comment: eu editei minha resposta e adicionei um break, veja se chega ao resultado que você espera.

Comment: Depois que eu coloquei o `break` só está imprimindo a `meta` tag que está no `if`, e essa `meta` tag está imprimindo em todas as páginas, pelo menos dessa vez não duplicou a `meta` tag. Eu atualizei a minha pergunta, por favor dê uma olhada no Edit.

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quer, olhei as tags só agora. Desculpe, editei a resposta.

Comment: É por causa dos nulls pronto, editado...

Comment: Continua do mesmo jeito, está ignorando a instrução do `else if`, e o resultado do `prin_r` continua do mesmo jeito que coloquei no Edit. Qual o motivo do NULL? Eu chequei os meus registros, e eles estão com o `entry_type` correto.

Answer (score 0):

Para você fazer isso aí que está querendo, tem que passar qual a chave do array associativo vai usar como valor dentro do array percorrido, pois a estrutura que o fechAll fera é a seguinte:

Array/Linha/Coluna, por exemplo:
Resultado(0,'entry_type') com pagina,
Resultado(1,'entry_type') com post,
Resultado(2,'entry_type') com article,
e assim por diante...
Com isto, sinlize no foreach após o 'as' o que deseja usar no array, como abaixo:

```
$mt = $conn->query("
    SELECT
       entry_type
    FROM myTable
    WHERE
       entry_type = 'pagina'
    GROUP BY
       entry_type");

$res = $mt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print("<pre>");
print_r($res);
print("</pre>");

foreach ($res as $FB) {
    if ($FB["entry_type"] == "pagina") {
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website">';
    } else {
        echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article">';
        echo '<meta property="article:author" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:publisher" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:published_time" content="">';
        echo '<meta property="article:modified_time" content="">';
    }
}
```

Comment: passa o PDO::FETCH_ASSOC dentro do fechAll que não vai mais aparecer duplicado e faz os WHERE e GROUP como você disse...

Comment: Editei a minha resposta ali em cima, e para mim aqui em casa, parece ter dado certo com a modificação. ele não ignorou mais o if...

Comment: Continua somente imprimindo as `meta` tags do `else`, eu coloquei alguns `print_r` o resultado ta no link: https://pastebin.com/ZuRspCRD Mesmo ainda não funcionando da maneira como eu queria, pelo `print_r` da pra ver que o `entry_type` atual é igual a `pagina`, mas mesmo assim ele insiste em imprimir o `else`, so imprimi o `if` se eu trocar o `if ($FB["entry_type"] == 'pagina')` por `if ($FB["entry_type"] != 'pagina')`. Eu tentei colocar outro `if` junto com o `else` `else if($FB["entry_type"] == 'post')` ainda não da certo.

Comment: Colocando o DFO>>FETCH_ASSO, pode tirar a chado do valor no foreach, ficando assim: foreach ($res as $FB). A chave eu só deixaria se não passasse o tipo de fetch que estou fazendo...

Comment: DFO>>FETCH_ASSO? Você quis dizer PDO::FETCH_ASSOC? Por favor explique melhor o seu comentario, eu realmente não entendi.

Comment: Pois é, foiy PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, deculpa cara, digitei muito na pressa e nem revisei, foi mal mesmo!

Comment: Tranquilo! A questão é que eu ainda continuo com o mesmo problema, eu só resolvi o problema com as duplicações. Eu não sei se você viu, mas eu adicionei novas informações na minha pergunta. Eu estou suspeitando de que o meu código está errado com relação ao que  eu quero fazer. Mas eu não conheço outro método pra fazer isso, além da condição `if` e `else`.  O que você acha? Alguma sujestão?

Comment: Na verdade eu usaria switch case, mas if também serve. você consegue garantir com toda certeza que o que vem do banco de dados é exatamente igual as possivilidade do if, incluindo maiúscula, munúsculas, acentos...